# Search text file for matching integer

Tags: java, java-io

I'm struggling to get my program to read through a text file and find a match for the number `num` with the `wrkID`, so it can print out relevant information.

The text file looks like this.  The numbers 455 and 367 are the `wrkID`, which I'm trying to get the number I input to match:

```
Corner street^3^455^Collin^Sydney
David street^2^367^Spence^Sydney
```

---

```
public class Work
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter filename >> ");
      String response = Keyboard.nextLine();
      File inFile = new File(response);
      Scanner wrk = new Scanner(inFile);
      System.out.print("Enter job ID >> ");
      int num = Keyboard.nextInt();

      while (route.hasNextLine())
      {
          String Street = wrk.nextLine();
          int stopNum = wrk.nextInt();
          int wrkID = wrk.nextInt();
          String road = wrk.nextLine();
          String town = wrk.nextLine();
          if(wrkID == num)
          {
            System.out.println("work id and street:  " + trkID + Street);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your input formatted?

Comment: @jackarms I'm fairly new to java os i don't even know

Comment: BufferedReader, FileReader, and String.split() is all you need

Comment: @GiovaniGrifante how would i apply those?

Comment: @Majeet that isn't a Java thing, just what is an example of a file that is used as input? Also you never define `route` in the code above?

Comment: @jackarms yep, i have fixed the route error, my bad

Answer (score 0):

problem here:

```
      String Street = wrk.nextLine();
      int stopNum = wrk.nextInt();
      int wrkID = wrk.nextInt();
      String road = wrk.nextLine();
      String town = wrk.nextLine();
```

when you call wrk.nextLine() it is assigning the entire first  line of text into the String street...
if you just need the integers, then throw away the other input by simply using nextInt();

Answer (score 0):

This should print the whole line if the given input matches .

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {

   Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter filename >> ");
      String response = Keyboard.nextLine();
   File file = new File(response);
   try {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      System.out.print("Enter job ID >> ");
      String num = Keyboard.nextLine();
     String line;
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] splitData = line.split("\\^");
         for(String data:splitData){
         if (data.equalsIgnoreCase(num))  {
            System.out.println(line);
         }
         }
     }

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```